# Riddle: "Halo of water, / tongue of wood..."

Tags: riddle

Another riddle:

> Halo of water,
>  Tongue of wood.
>  Skin of stone,
>  Long I've
> stood.
>  My fingers short,
>  Reach to the sky.
>  Inside my
> heart,
>  Men live and die.
>  What am I?

What is the answer?

Comment: Nice riddle! Simple, descriptive, answer is clear when you see it but involves some nondirect clues.

Comment: Coming from the big honcho of Puzzling SE? thanks man

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you are a

> Castle

Halo of water,

> Moat

Tongue of wood.

> Drawbridge

Skin of stone,

> Castle walls

Long I've stood.

> Usually castles are quite old

My fingers short
Reach to the sky.

> Merlons

Inside my heart
Men live and die.

> Castles are fortified structures often built for their defensive advantages but still many would have been stormed and witnessed death within.

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> Castle.

Halo of Water

> a moat

Tongue of wood

> the drawbridge

Skin of Stone,
Long I've stood

> you're made of stones and most castles are hundreds of years old

My fingers short
reach to the sky

> you have towers and battlements that can be fairly tall

Inside my heart
Men live and die

> A castle is a place of residence.

Comment: dude, you said almost the same as hexomino did a bit earlier

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities Just 2 minutes in it, I guess they were both writing at the same time.

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities Yeah, I guess I'm not as fast a typist as hexomino.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

In answer to...
Halo of water,
Tongue of wood.
Skin of stone,
Long I've stood.
My fingers short
Reach to the sky.
Inside my heart
Men live and die.
What am I?

You are Earth.

Comment: The halo would be air, although water _does_ cover like 70% of Earth (not sure). It would be more appropiate to think of the wooden tongue as a lot of hair (trees), and men do not like to live in magma. Anyway, cool thinking! (remember, as a new user, that it is _much_ better to explain your reasoning, like @hexominion did)